# Get cells of rows

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm successfully getting the rows of a table as so:

```
var rows = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.summary > tbody > tr'), element => $(element)))
```

How do I get the children of each row as an array?

Do I do `... Array.from(rows[i].querySelectorAll(...`?

I've tried a few different methods but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question so that you want to get only the values of cells grouped as an array for each of the rows present in a table. If that's correct, then you could do it in this way:

```
  const rows = await page.evaluate(
    () => Array.from( document.querySelectorAll('table > tbody > tr') ) // Get the rows as an array
      .map(row => Array.from( row.querySelectorAll("td") ) // For each row get its cells as an array
      .map(td => td.textContent)) // Replace each cell in the latter array with its text
  )
```

Comment: Thanks mate, glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you might be looking to do something along these lines

```
const rows = await page.evaluate(
  () => Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('.summary > tbody > tr'),
    element => $(element)
  )
)

let children = []

for (const row of rows)
  children = [...children, ...row.children]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

Use the following code, which queries the direct child elements of the `tr` elements:

```js
const rowChildren = await page.$$('.summary > tbody > tr > *');
```

### Long Answer

Your code is not doing what you think it is doing. I go over your code, to show you the problem.

**Problem**

Here is your code again:

```js
var rows = await page.evaluate(
  () => Array.from(
    document.querySelectorAll('.summary > tbody > tr'),
    element => $(element),
  )
)
```

What this code does is:

1. Run `document.querySelectorAll` in the browser
2. Map each element in the NodeList to a jQuery object (I'm assuming `$` is jQuery here)
3. Call `JSON.stringify` on the array of jQuery objects (to serialize them)
4. puppeteer transfers your serialized data from the browser environment to the Node.js environment
5. `rows` now contains an array of "jQuery objects", without reference to their actual DOM node

So, this code does not give you the handle to the jQuery elements in the Node.js environment as the function [`page.evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) can only return serializable objects (which DOM nodes are not). Although it looks like you successfully queried the DOM nodes, these objects are just the "jQuery wrappers" around the DOM nodes without the actual DOM nodes as these were not serialized.

**Solution**

To query DOM nodes from the browser environment, you have to use a function like [`page.$$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1), which can return [ElementHandles](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#class-elementhandle). Therefore, using the following code, will return the actual `tr` rows:

```js
const rows = await page.$$('.summary > tbody > tr');
```

To then further query their child elements, you can simply add a `> *` selector to the end, which will query all direct child nodes of the `tr` rows:

```js
const rowChildren = await page.$$('.summary > tbody > tr > *');
```

Comment: I've tried this now. One issue: Cells are not grouped. There are two cells in each row. This code returns an array of each cell separated from its row.